# Find the length of the curve $(x-y)^2=a(x+y)$ , $x^2-y^2=\frac98 z^2$ from the point $O(0,0,0)$ to $A(x_0,y_0,z_0)$

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

Find the length of the curve $(x-y)^2=a(x+y)$ , $x^2-y^2=\frac98 z^2$  from the point $O(0,0,0)$ to $A(x_0,y_0,z_0)$  $(z_0 \gt0)$

I have the solution in my book but what I'm struggling with is understanding the question.

Can somebody explain it to me what am I exactly finding?

Comment: Suppose you walk for a road defined by those formulas. You start at point $0$ (yes, it belongs to the road) and measure the distance you walk until you reach at point $A$ which also belongs to the road.

Comment: But I can't see what is the connection between these two curves. Is the intersection the road you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, the intersection is the "road"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

The aspect of a given curve does not depend of an isotropic coordinates transform. So making $u = x + y$ and $v = x - y$ we have

$$
v^2- a u = 0\\
u v -b z^2 = 0
$$

now we can find

$$
u = u(z)\\
v = v(z)
$$

so the representation can be done with a parametric plotting of $(u(z),v(z),z)$ as follows

[image]

```
sols = Solve[{v^2 == a u, u v == b z^2}, {u, v}]
ParametricPlot3D[({u, v, z} /. sols[[1]] /. {a -> 1, b ->9/8}), {z, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
```

The curve length can be calculated as

$$
l = \int_{z=0}^{z=z_0}\sqrt{1+u'^2+v'^2}dz
$$

NOTE

See below the comment by GEdgar.

Comment: Thank you for this but it's not what I'm asking. I want to know what does this represent in space?

Comment: The curve is as attached.

Comment: Good idea.  However, note that the change of variables $u = x + y$ and $v = x - y$ is not isometric, it shrinks (or expands) by $\sqrt{2}$.  So I guess you will want to adjuct $z$ by $\sqrt{2}$ also; or else use $u = (x + y)/\sqrt2$ and $v = (x - y)/\sqrt2$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for your pertinent comment.